# Mockito. Spy doReturn doesn't change return value

Tags: java, mockito

I want to test the method `calculateApiTokenExpireDate()`. I created a spy for `currentDateTime()` so that it returns static date. But it still returns the current date.
Could someone plese show me where is my mistake?
Thanks

```
public class ServiceHelper {

    static final long DEFAULT_OUTDATED_TIME_MILLIS = 86400000;
    static final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

    long oneTimeOutDatedMillis = DEFAULT_OUTDATED_TIME_MILLIS;

    protected String getApiTokenExpireDate(){
        DateTimeFormatter customFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
        LocalDateTime tokenExpireDate = calculateApiTokenExpireDate();
        return tokenExpireDate.format(customFormat);
    }

    protected LocalDateTime calculateApiTokenExpireDate(){
        LocalDateTime now = currentDateTime();
        return now.plus(oneTimeOutDatedMillis, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    }

    protected LocalDateTime currentDateTime() {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

```
public class ServiceHelperTest {

    private ServiceHelper serviceToTest;

    private ServiceHelper spy;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        serviceToTest = new ServiceHelper();
        serviceToTest.oneTimeOutDatedMillis = 86400000;
        spy = Mockito.spy(serviceToTest);
    }

    @Test
    void calculateApiTokenExpireDate_return_plus_one_day_date() {
        /* prepare */
        doReturn(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 1, 24, 14, 1)).when(spy).currentDateTime();

        /* execute */
        LocalDateTime tokenExpireDate = serviceToTest.calculateApiTokenExpireDate();

        /* test */
        assertEquals(2023, tokenExpireDate.getYear());
        assertEquals(1, tokenExpireDate.getMonthValue());
        assertEquals(25, tokenExpireDate.getDayOfMonth());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to `this` cannot be spied, because the `this` reference is not changed. You can change your class to accept in a `java.time.Clock` instance or on a function/interface which returns the current date/time. Then you can inject `Clock#fixed()` in your tests.

Class:

```
public class ServiceHelper {

    static final long DEFAULT_OUTDATED_TIME_MILLIS = 86400000;
    static final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

    private final Clock clock;

    long oneTimeOutDatedMillis = DEFAULT_OUTDATED_TIME_MILLIS;

    public ServiceHelper(final Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    // ...

    protected LocalDateTime calculateApiTokenExpireDate(){
        LocalDateTime now = currentDateTime();
        return now.plus(oneTimeOutDatedMillis, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
    }

    protected LocalDateTime currentDateTime() {
        return LocalDateTime.now(clock);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class ServiceHelperTest {
    private ServiceHelper serviceToTest;
    private Instant now;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        /* prepare */
        now = Instant.now(); // or: Instant.parse("...")
        serviceToTest = new ServiceHelper(Clock.fixed(now, ZoneOffset.UTC));
        serviceToTest.oneTimeOutDatedMillis = 86400000;

    }

    @Test
    void calculateApiTokenExpireDate_return_plus_one_day_date() {
        /* execute */
        LocalDateTime tokenExpireDate = serviceToTest.calculateApiTokenExpireDate();

        /* test */
        // assert against this.now ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mocking the wrong instance of the class. In the test case, you are mocking the `spy` instance of the `ServiceHelper` class, but you are calling the method on the `serviceToTest` instance, which is the original "unmocked" object. To fix this, you should call the method on the spy instance, like this:

```java
LocalDateTime tokenExpireDate = spy.calculateApiTokenExpireDate();
```

Also I would recommend you to read [that section](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) from official documentation with quite good examples.